# AVAudioSession AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avaudiosession

I would like to record videos with audio using `AVCaptureSession`. For this I need the AudioSessionCategory `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`, since my app also plays back video with sound.

I want audio to be audible from the default speaker and I want it to mix with other audio. So I need the options `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker  | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`.

If I do the following while other audio is playing there is a clear audible glitch in the audio from the other app:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Is there a way to get rid of this glitch?

It seems to occur when the there's a `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonRouteConfigurationChange` as notified by `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange` from no mic input, to mic input.

The configuration change (and glitch) also occurs when the app goes to the background (with or without deactivating the audio session). When returning from the background without deactivating the audio session, the glitches start to occur when the `AVCaptureSession` configuration is changed i.e. when the camera is switched from front to back. In this case the audio routing is not touched, and it only occurs when returning from the background without deactivating the audio session. The notification that the route changes is fired twice. Once to disable the mic, and once to enable it again.

Note that this behavior is easily reproducible by downloading Apple's AVCamManual example. Add the following to the `viewDidLoad` of `AAPLCameraViewController.m`:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
…
session.usesApplicationAudioSession = YES;
session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

Some other weird thing, which might be related:

Set the audio category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` first and activate it:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient withOptions:0 error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

and then change the category:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
```

other audio stops playing despite the options flag. No errors are thrown.

Comment: I have all the same problems. To the letter. Any news on this?

Comment: For your last example where audio stops playing despite the options flag. Audio continues playing if you deactivate audio session (`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];`) 
before setting the category `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];`.

And re-activate after
(`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];`)

Comment: Also having the same problems, tried using `PlayAndRecord` all the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496563/avcapturesession-addinput-causing-glitch-in-background-audio. Also tried work around by changing the category from `Ambient` when recording starts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615707/avaudiosession-setcategory-not-working. Please let me know if you've found a solution for either method

Comment: Apple says the audio glitch for PlayAndRecord has no workaround: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/74778#74778. So I guess the only option is to change the category, but this doesn't work either? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615707/avaudiosession-setcategory-not-working

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by @Cbas in the comments, an Apple Staff has confirmed there is glitch when switching from output-only to input+output routes and that there is no workaround for that issue, a possible workaround is to totally avoid switching from output-only to input-output routes by always use the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category even when the app is not recording.
Also, don't set the audio session category again if it has already be set to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or the glitch will occur.

Comment: caveat: using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord disables the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter (on lock screen)

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.captureSession startRunning];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
```

When capureSession startRunning, deactive current audioSession and resume other interrupted music app on the background use this option `AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation`.

Reset the category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` with current audioSession,and avtive again.

I hope it works for you.