# AVAudioSession setCategory not working

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avaudiosession, avcapturedevice

I have a video capturing app and I want to be able to play background music while recording audio+video.

I can accomplish this if I set the `AVAudioSession` category to `PlayAndRecord` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. However, this causes a glitch in the audio whenever the view with the camera enters or exits the foreground, and its apparently impossible to get rid of: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/74778#74778

I can live with the glitch if it just happens when I start/stop recording video, but that means I need to change the `AVAudioSession` category from `Ambient` to `PlayAndRecord` when a button is pressed, and this also seems to not be possible.

How do I change the `AVAudioSession` category?

I tried this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                       error:nil];
```

But the background music stops when the recording starts.

Following this post: [AVCaptureSession and background audio iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869802/avcapturesession-and-background-audio-ios-7)

I tried deactivating the session then setting the category:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
         withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker
               error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:&error];
```

I also tried listening for the `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` and setting the category in that handler after deactivating the session. But the background music always turns off when the app starts recording.

Why can't I change the `AVAudioSession` category?

Comment: In simple words app recording not working while music ... and you want both to work together right ??

Comment: yes, but it needs to start in Ambient mode

Answer (score 0):

Please try this category

AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute

or check both categories 
AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord | AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord